# PHP check if user typed something in text input

Tags: php, html, trim

I have a few simple html text inputs.  I would like to check that the user inputted something and not just spaces.  My code below isn't working.

HTML (in a form):

```
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' />
```

PHP (the "action" page of the form):

```
$email=mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower(trim($_POST['email'])));

    if (!$email || empty($email)){    // these are the checks that don't work
           echo "no email entered";
     }
```

Comment: Did you check what is in `$_POST[]` ?

Comment: Check what is in `$_POST['email']` prior to your "action" portion. Also, to be clear, when you say *not working*, you mean "no email entered" isn't displaying when there is an empty email variable?

Comment: I gave up, your code looks good to me.

Comment: I think you'll be able to close that corner by applying some sort of basic email syntax verification (ie, that it's in the format *@*.*), that would eliminate the risk of empty responses as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you should use mysql_real_escape_string only when inputting data inside of mysql. Don't use it while checking.

My typical manual verification syntax is this:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['email']) || strlen(trim($_REQUEST['email'])) == 0){
    $errors[] = 'No email provided';
}
```

Then after checking, use mysql_real_escape_string while inputting data into mysql

```
mysql_query('UPDATE myusers SET email = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']).'" WHERE id = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']).'"');
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head I would try

```
$email = trim($email);

if (!isset($email)){ 
    echo "no email entered";
}
```

or

```
if ($email == ''){ 
    echo "no email entered";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(preg_match('/[[:space:]]*/',$email){
    echo "no email entered";
}
```

this way you avoid also **newlines** and **tabs**.

Comment: is simple and efficient. What's the problem?

Comment: Well, there's the usual argument about regex being excessively resource-intensive -- which it is, but not enough so as to cause a performance difference unless the operation is repeated many times. I would argue the issue is more importantly a **semantic** one: PHP has built-in functions to handle this sort of thing. If a built-in solution exists, you should prefer it to general, broad-based solutions designed to handle any conceivable scenario (like regex).

Answer (score 0):

just change the type of the input field from 'text' to 'email' 
It will automatically check if someone is entered a valid email or not.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Please provide a sufficient level of details in your answer even if you think it is a simple issue or you want to refer to a link or whatsoever.